# Tag Plus is Protected в Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

Задал такую функцию в Вольфраме:

```
cya3dMechFunc[alpha_] := 
    If[alpha < a13dMech, KRe*KM*(cya3dproizvodnaya*(alpha - a03dMech)), KRe*(c0Mech + c1Mech*alpha + c2Mech*alpha^2)]
```

Дальше пытаюсь использовать ее внутри другой функции:

```
 cxapMech[alpha_] := 
     cxamin2d + 
      deltaCxapMech*(1 + (
         0.75*(cya3dMechFunc[alpha] - cyfMech)^2)/(cyamax3dMech - 
           cyfMech)^2)
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
 SetDelayed::write: Tag Plus in (0.0071 +0.0838 (1+(0.75 cya3dMech)/\[Placeholder]))[alpha_] is Protected.
```

Чтоо не так?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил переименовав `cxapMech[alpha_]` на `cxapMechFunc[alpha_]`